# Mixing Multiple conditions in a Single NgStyle Tag?

Tags: css, angular

I have a NgStyle Tag and I want to use multiple conditions in it, but either it doesn't work or I receive errors.

So far, this is my code:

```
 <div class = "card" [ngStyle]="{'height': Card.duration.Hours == 1 ? '130px': height}"
                      [ngStyle]="{'height': Card.duration.Hours < 1 ? '100px': height}"
  >
```

but only the first condition works and when I want to mix these I receive errors. how can I have multiple conditions?

Comment: Are you using multiple [ngStyle] properties inside one html tag. can you post your full html code ?

Comment: See my answer and let me know if this worked for you?

Comment: Then what you need?

Comment: this works for only one condition, but when I add something Like this:     
 <div class = "card" [ngClass]="{'height100':(Card.duration.Hours ===1), 'height200':((Card.duration.Hours ===1)&&(1<=Card.duration.Minutes<=59))}">

it shows all of them at the same size

Comment: same goes for
 <div class = "card" [ngClass]="{'height100':(Card.duration.Hours ===1),'height200':((Card.duration.Hours ===1 && 1<=Card.duration.Minutes<=59))}">

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda it just overrides

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow @Dorian, as you can see there are a few answers, now. Please choose the best one which solved your issue and mark it as the right answer, or response to the answers, if no one solves your issue. To lean more about how Stack Overflow works, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use multiple `[ngStyle]` in one `div` tag. use `[ngClass]` instead.
Below is my sample example.

**HTML**

```
<div  [ngClass]="{ 'height100': hours === 1, 'height200': hours === 2, 'height300': hours === 3}">
  test
</div>
```

**TS**

```
export class AppComponent  {

  hours: number = 3;

  constructor () {

  }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.height100 {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.height200 {
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}

.height300 {
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
}
```

**[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wd1nw4)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[ngStyle]="{'height': ((Card.duration.Hours == 1) ? '130px' : height)}"

Comment: Try This.  It should work

[ngStyle]="{'height': (Card.duration.Hours == 1) ?  '130px' : ( (Card.duration.Hours < 1 ) ? '100px '  :  height)}"

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
[ngStyle]="{'height': Card.duration.Hours == 1 ? '130px': ( Card.duration.Hours < 1 ? 100px : height)}"
```